# Multiple Values after Comparison Operator

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to display different content based on user location.
I'm using this code here:

```
<div id="res"></div>  
  <script>
    $.get('https://ipinfo.io', (res) => {
      if(res.country !== 'NL'){
        $('#res').html(`
          <p>Instert Cool HTML stuff here</p>
        `)
      }
    },'jsonp');
  </script>
```

I was trying to add more country tags after the 'NL' like this:

`(res.country !== 'NL''DE')`

or like this

`(res.country !== 'NL','DE')`

or like this

```
(res.country !== 'NL' ||
 res.country !== 'DE'
)
```

None of them seems to be working...

Comment: The last one is closest, but it should be `&&` not `||`

Comment: Yes, it's working thank you friend.